# Save interactive matplotlib figures to html

Tags: python, matplotlib

I realize that there have been quite a few questions asked on this over the years, but the answers I have found thus far have been fairly unsatisfactory, and that may be just because there is no way to easily accomplish this. I have a notebook that generates interactive figures with the `% matplotlib notebook` magic command, but when I use nbconvert to get the HTML for the notebook, the interactivity of the figures is lost. Is there a way to save the javascript and raw data of each figure directly into the HTML output to maintain interactivity? If not, can someone outline a few possible alternative solutions that I can look into?

Comment: Use Bokeh to generate interactive, java based graphs.  I can only guess that your figures are interactive because you're using some widgets, since there is no code here.

Comment: If using matplotlib and wanting interactivity that will require python running (either locally or on a server). Hence you cannot show the matplotlib figure in a pure html version. Alternatives for interactive figures may be plotly, bokeh, mpld3.

Comment: the only relevant piece of code is `% matplotlib notebook` which makes all figures interactive. After a quick lookup, it seems that with Bokeh I would have to replot all my figures with their library, which seems tedious, especially considering that my plots are fairly complicated, but i will definitely take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest right, because the html converter doesnt have access to the python kernel that actually has the data. makes sense i guess

Comment: The other option is to post your notebooks on a notebook server.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you want the figures to be interactive.

Comment: Posting the notebook on a server isn't an option unfortunately. In fact it's already on a sever. I just need to get all the outputs into a new webpage (like a report sort of). @JodyKlymak the reason i want interactivity is because the plot has 100k data points and i'd like users to be able to zoom on areas of interest. Think of it like a time series